# least squares fitting to a 3 dimensional data set

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I am working on video stabilisation ( making shaky videos non-shaky) using matlab.
One of the steps is to find a smooth camera path given the unstable camera path.
The unstable camera path is one which gives the jittering or shake to the video.
I have camera path specified using camera position which is a 3d-data.
camera path - (cx,cy,cz);

As i plot in matlab, i can visually see the shakiness of the camera motion.
So now i require a least squares fitting to be done on the camera path specified by(cx,cy,cz);

I came across polyfit() which does fitting for 2-dimensional data.
But what i need is a 3-d smooth curve fit to the shaky curve.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach using least square fit:

```
t = (1:0.1:5)';

% model
px = [ 5 2 1 ];
x =  polyval(px,t);

py = [ -2 1 1 ];
y = polyval(py,t);

pz = [ 1 20 1 ];
z = polyval(pz,t);

%  plot model
figure
plot3(x,y,z)
hold all

% simulate measurement 
xMeasured = x+2*(rand(length(x),1)-0.5);
yMeasured = y+2*(rand(length(y),1)-0.5);
zMeasured = z+2*(rand(length(z),1)-0.5);

% plot simulated measurements
plot3(xMeasured, yMeasured, zMeasured,'or')
hold off
grid on

% least squares fit 
A = [t.^2, t, t./t];
pxEstimated = A\xMeasured;
pyEstimated = A\yMeasured;
pzEstimated = A\zMeasured;
```

Comment: I am a novice user of matlab. Will you take your time modifying your example and explain me about how the least squares fitting is done. The modification you can put is that 'instead of having t defined and then doing some polyval to get x,y,z' you are already given (cx,cy,cz) coordinates and then how do you define the matrix A in this case and do a least squares fit ?

Comment: @gansai: All you have to do is replacing xMeasured with cx,  yMeasured with cy and zMeasured with cz, respecting dimensions. 't' is the time vector for the applied polynomial model x=a*t^2+b*t+c. The least square fit is done through the mldivide command '\'.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just fit three separate 1d curves for cx(t), cy(t), cz(t)?

BTW: I think what you need is a Kalman filter, not a polynomial fit to the camera path. But I'm not sure if matlab has builtin support for that.

Comment: Yes—try this FEX submission: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5377-learning-the-kalman-filter

Comment: No, I need to obtain a 3d curve which represents the smooth path. I could have used Kalman filter, but as I am trying to implement a paper, I am following the algorithm there which does it without using a Kalman filter.

Comment: @gansai: Where do you think is the difference between fitting one 3d curve and fitting three 1d functions? If you use least squares to fit a polynomial, I don't think there is any difference.

Comment: ok. As I am a naive user of matlab I ask this: How should I fit three 1d functions to cx,cy,cz? and i don't have a parameter 't' in my problem.

Comment: @gansai: Then you need to explain what cx/cy/cz are. I thought these were coordinates in a 3d space that the camera had when it acquired each frame. Then t would be the time of each frame.

Comment: Yes cx, cy, cz represents the coordinates in the 3d space. But the parameter 't' is nothing but at time t I obtained the 't'th frame and I have a 't'th coordinate (cx,cy,cz) recorded. To be most specific, I have 343 frames of a video. And as I am implementing the paper in the following link: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~fliu/project/3dstab.htm where the author uses a software 'Voodoo Camera Tracker' which given the input as a set of frames produces the output which contains the various camera parameters. So I have 343 parameter values. And taking the unstable camera path I need to do a lsq fit.

Answer (score 0):

Let me be grateful to stackoverflow.com first of all and then my thanks to zellus and nikie who had started me thinking about the problem more. So now I have reached the solution which follows zellus approach and as nikie pointed out I used parameter 't' .
cx, cy,cz are the coordinates in 3d space and in my case they are all 343x1 doubles 
My final code is shown below which fits the 3d data set:

```
t = linspace(1,343,343)';

 load cx.mat;
 load cy.mat;
 load cz.mat;

 plot3(cx, cy, cz,'r'),title('source Camera Path');
 hold all

 A = [t.^2, t, t./t];
 fx = A\cx;
 fy = A\cy;
 fz = A\cz;


 Xev = polyval(fx,t);
 Yev = polyval(fy,t);
 Zev = polyval(fz,t);

 plot3(Xev,Yev,Zev,'+b'),title('Fitting Line');
```

I look forward to more interesting discussions on StackOverflow with great helpful people.

Comment: It's better to edit your question and add the answer there in an UPDATE or something, and be sure to accept the answer you feel helped the most (in this case, there are two, but just accept the "better" one). Also, indent your code by 4 spaces, or select it and press the code button (1010) to format it nicely.